# How do I redirect a Nav.Link to an ".html" page?

Tags: html, reactjs

I have a react navbar on my site and I would like to redirect my page to an .html page, but it's not working properly.

this is the component I am using, with the href reference to the QR CODE page, at the same level that the component page is using.

project link: https://github.com/rudsonramon/customerservice.git

```
import React from 'react';
import { FaHome } from 'react-icons/fa';
import FormControl from 'react-bootstrap/FormControl';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';;

function HeaderContainer() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Container>
                <Navbar fixed="top" bg="primary" variant="dark">
                    <Navbar.Brand href="#home">ConcertTI</Navbar.Brand>
                    <Nav className="mr-auto">
                        <Nav.Link href="#home"> <FaHome /> </Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link href="QrCode.html" target='_self'>QR Code</Nav.Link>
                    </Nav>

                    <Form inline>
                        <FormControl type="text" placeholder="Search" className="mr-sm-2" />
                        <Button variant="outline-light">Procurar</Button>
                    </Form>
                </Navbar>
            </Container>
        </div>
    )

}

export default HeaderContainer;
```

Comment: Is `QrCode.html` is in same project folder?

Comment: I think this should be done from ngnix server

Comment: @ravibagul91, the QrCode.html is in the same project folder.

Comment: @JaisaRam, I am executing it local, with no nginx server.

Comment: Just give it a try, `<Nav.Link href="%PUBLIC_URL%/QrCode.html" target='_self'>QR Code</Nav.Link>`

Answer (score -1):

`./Qrcode.html` directs it to a **sub folder** named *Qrcode.html*.
remove the `./` and try again.

Comment: Thanks @chambers, but it is still reloading the same page and the redirect is not working, anyway.